# Why we need to escape CSS?

Tags: css, string, escaping

Given the following examples which I picked up from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape):

```
CSS.escape(".foo#bar")        // "\.foo\#bar"
CSS.escape("()[]{}")          // "\(\)\[\]\{\}"
```

Since `.foo#bar` is a valid CSS selector expression. Why we need to append `\` before some characters? Suppose I want to write my own program which does the same task of escaping all the values/expressions in a CSS file then, how should I proceed?

PS: I am always confused about the escaping, how should I think when it comes to escaping some input?

Comment: "Suppose I want to write my own program which does the same task, how should I proceed?" This question makes no sense on its own. What task?

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You escape strings only when those strings contain special symbols that you want to be treated literally. If you are expecting a valid CSS selector as user input, you shouldn't be escaping anything.

`.foo#bar` is a valid CSS selector, but it means something completely different from `\.foo\#bar`. The former matches an element with that respective class and ID, e.g. `<div class=foo id=bar>` in HTML. The latter matches an element with the element name ".foo#bar", which in a hypothetical markup language could be represented as `<.foo#bar>` (obviously this is not legal HTML or XML syntax, but you get the picture).